# Reading from a file gets only the first character

Tags: c, arrays, string

I need to write a program in C that reads 2 columns of data.

The file looks like this:

```
value1 4.34
value2 45.4
value3 35325.34
```

and so on.
EDIT !!
Here's my code so far:

```
void readin()
{
#include <stdio.h>
FILE *input;
int i,x=1;
float value[5];
int name[5];
if (input == NULL)
{
    printf("Error");
}
for (i=1; i <5; i++)
{
    fscanf(input,"%s %f \n", &name[i],%value[i]);
}
for (x=1; x<5; x++)
{
 x=i
printf("\n %c &.5f", name[i],value[i]);
i++;
}
fclose(input);
```

}

When I put a `%c` in the `fscanf` statement, only the first letter is read. Also, I always get some segmentation fault.

What do I need to change so that the program reads the entire name?

Comment: I don't think `%value[i]` will even compile and you've not shown us enough to reproduce your code. (Show a minimal, complete example that reproduces the problem).

Comment: That still isn't a *complete* program. Show something with everything you need to feed it into a compiler and reproduce it anywhere.

Comment: i edited it. its better now

Comment: Please be kind to others here. Post code that you have compiled and used to build a program.

Answer (score 0):

```
void readin(){
    FILE *input;
    int i, x;
    float value[5];
    char name[5][16];

    input = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return ;
    }
    for (i=0; i <5; i++)
    {
        if(2!=fscanf(input, "%15s %f", name[i], &value[i]))
            break;
    }
    for (x=0; x<i; x++)
    {
        printf("%s %.5f\n", name[x], value[x]);
    }
    fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

But this doesn't print out more that one letter.. i dont know why.. :/

it only prints

V 23.112
V 12.22
V 2.231